# Why my train and validation accuracy raising too slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

Here is my code.I dont know why my train and validation accuracy increase too slow.Is that normal? I’m new at deep learning.This is my homework.Train and validation values dont change nearly till loop 500.Is that normal? I changed learning rate and add weight_decay etc. but i didnt see difference

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Libraries
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import autograd, nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
from torch.utils import data


"""
Olivetti face dataset
"""
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces

# Olivetti dataset download
olivetti = fetch_olivetti_faces()
train = olivetti.images
label = olivetti.target

X = train
Y = label

print("\nDownload Ok")


"""
Set for train
"""
train_rate = 0.8

X_train = np.zeros([int(train_rate * X.shape[0]),64,64], dtype=float)
Y_train = np.zeros([int(train_rate * X.shape[0])], dtype=int)

X_val = np.zeros([int((1-train_rate) * X.shape[0]+1),64,64], dtype=float)
Y_val = np.zeros([int((1-train_rate) * X.shape[0]+1)], dtype=int)

#Split data for train and validation
ie=0
iv=0
for i in range(X.shape[0]):

    if (i%10)/9 <= train_rate:
        X_train[ie] = X[i]
        Y_train[ie] = Y[i]
        ie += 1
    else:
        X_val[iv] = X[i]
        Y_val[iv] = Y[i]
        iv += 1

X_train = X_train.reshape(320,-1,64,64)
X_val = X_val.reshape(80,-1,64,64)

print(Y_train.shape)
X_train = torch.Tensor(X_train)
Y_train = torch.Tensor(Y_train)

X_val = torch.Tensor(X_val)
Y_val = torch.Tensor(Y_val)  

batch_size = 16

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(X_train, 
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            )
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(X_val, 
                                            batch_size=batch_size, 
                                            )

class CNNModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModule, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 13 * 13, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 40)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 13 * 13)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


def make_train(model,dataset,n_iters,gpu):

    # Organize data
    X_train,Y_train,X_val,Y_val = dataset

    kriter = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=0.03)

    #Arrays to save loss and accuracy
    tl=np.zeros(n_iters)    #For train loss
    ta=np.zeros(n_iters)    #For train accuracy
    vl=np.zeros(n_iters)    #For validation loss
    va=np.zeros(n_iters)    #For validation accuracy

    # Convert labels to long
    Y_train = Y_train.long()
    Y_val = Y_val.long()

    # GPU control
    if gpu:
        X_train,Y_train = X_train.cuda(),Y_train.cuda()
        X_val,Y_val = X_val.cuda(),Y_val.cuda()
        model = model.cuda() # Parameters to GPU!
        print("Using GPU")
    else:
        print("Using CPU")
        # print(X_train.shape)
        # print(Y_train.shape)

    for i in range(n_iters):  


        # train forward
        train_out = model.forward(X_train)
        train_loss = kriter(train_out,Y_train)

        # Backward and optimization
        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()



        # Compute train accuracy
        train_predict = train_out.cpu().detach().argmax(dim=1)
        train_accuracy = (train_predict.cpu().numpy()==Y_train.cpu().numpy()).mean()

        # For validation
        val_out = model.forward(X_val)
        val_loss = kriter(val_out,Y_val)

        # Compute validation accuracy
        val_predict = val_out.cpu().detach().argmax(dim=1)
        val_accuracy = (val_predict.cpu().numpy()==Y_val.cpu().numpy()).mean()

        tl[i] = train_loss.cpu().detach().numpy()
        ta[i] = train_accuracy
        vl[i] = val_loss.cpu().detach().numpy()
        va[i] = val_accuracy

        # Show result each 5 loop
        if i%5==0:
            print("Loop --> ",i)
            print("Train Loss :",train_loss.cpu().detach().numpy())
            print("Train Accuracy :",train_accuracy)
            print("Validation Loss :",val_loss.cpu().detach().numpy())
            print("Validation Accuracy :",val_accuracy)

    model = model.cpu()

    #Print result
    plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n_iters), tl, 'r-')
    plt.subplot(2,2,2)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n_iters), ta, 'b--')

    plt.subplot(2,2,3)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n_iters), vl, 'r-')
    plt.subplot(2,2,4)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n_iters), va, 'b--')    


dataset = X_train,Y_train,X_val,Y_val

gpu =  True
gpu = gpu and torch.cuda.is_available() 


model = CNNModule()
make_train(model,dataset,1000,gpu)
```

OUTPUT:
Loop -->  0
Train Loss : 3.6910985
Train Accuracy : 0.025
Validation Loss : 3.6908844
Validation Accuracy : 0.025
Loop -->  5

---

Loop -->  215
Train Loss : 3.6849258
Train Accuracy : 0.025
Validation Loss : 3.6850574
Validation Accuracy : 0.025

---

Loop -->  500
Train Loss : 3.4057992
Train Accuracy : 0.103125
Validation Loss : 3.5042462
Validation Accuracy : 0.0875

---

Loop -->  995
Train Loss : 0.007807272
Train Accuracy : 1.0
Validation Loss : 0.64222467
Validation Accuracy : 0.8375

[OUTPUT GRAPH IMAGE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCKd0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only problem - but please note that you zero the gradient, then do forward pass over the validation data. which means that new gradients of the validation data are stored in the model before the next iteration. The common practice should be to create some evaluation method, and use it to make prediction over the validation set without saving the gradients. something like:

```
def eval_model(data, X_val, Y_val):
    model.eval(); # this sets the model to be in inferrence mode (for example if you have batchNorm or droput layers)

    with torch.no_grad(): # tells the model to not compute gradients. 
        val_out = model.forward(X_val)
        val_loss = criterion(val_out,Y_val)

    # here put some prints or whatever you want to do

    model.train() # this returns the model to be in training mode
```